# What are the ways to sum matrix elements in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

Given the matrix:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
```

1. How could you use a for loop to compute the sum of the elements in the matrix?
2. Write a one line MATLAB command using the function `sum` to sum the
   matrix elements in `A`.

#### My answer:

1)

```
for j=1:3,
    for i=j:3,
        A(i,:) = A(i,:)+A(j+1,:)+A(j+2,:)
    end
end
```

2)

```
sum(A)
```

Are these the correct answers? I didn't know how to use `if`, `while` and `for`. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: These are really simple questions.  A few minutes on Google with one of the innumerable tutorials would have saved the rest of us alot of time.

Comment: Try to avoid using for-loops for calculating stuff in Matlab. Unless you really want to make things really slow or there is no other way.

Answer (score 31):

For very large matrices using `sum(sum(A))` can be faster than `sum(A(:))`:

```
>> A = rand(20000);
>> tic; B=sum(A(:)); toc; tic; C=sum(sum(A)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.407980 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.322624 seconds.
```

Comment: Nice find! Actually it even seems to be faster for nearly any size. Even for `rand(100)` the difference is significant on my system. (Though not for  `rand(10000,1)`). However, as it is about a fraction of a second I would still recommend the more robust/general `sum(A(:))` for most purposes.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin I prefer ``sum(sum(A))`` since it is more computationally efficient. The only advantage of ``sum(A(:))`` is that it is easier to read but it recodes the whole matrix A into a vector, thus the computational effort.

Comment: @MarioReutter Of course it is less efficient (as shown in the answer), but actually the main reason why I use it is that it works for matrices of higher dimensionality as well. Suppose you have `M=rand(3,3,3)`, now compare `sum(sum(M)))` with `sum(M(:))`.

Comment: Update: using Matlab 2015b, the difference is roughly an order of magnitude smaller (0.193 sec. v. 0.185 sec.).

Comment: `timeit(@()sum(sum(A)))/timeit(@()sum(A(:)))` is more accurate than `tic` and `toc`.

Answer (score 18):

1)

```
total = 0;
for i=1:size(A,1)
  for j=1:size(A,2)
    total = total + A(i,j);
  end
end
```

2)

```
total = sum(A(:));
```

Comment: And if you use 1) instead of 2) when you are actually using MATLAB for something real, then you need to die a slow horrible death ;)

Comment: While a correct answer, I would hope to see the most up-ed answer to discourage loops. They do indeed lead to slow horrible deaths...  Maybe edit it?

Answer (score 11):

Another answer for the first question is to use *one* for loop and perform [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/sept01/matrix.html) into the array using the function [NUMEL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/numel.html) to get the total number of elements:

```
total = 0;
for i = 1:numel(A)
  total = total+A(i);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Avoid for loops whenever possible.

```
sum(A(:))
```

is great however if you have some logical indexing going on you can't use the (:) but you can write

```
% Sum all elements under 45 in the matrix
sum ( sum ( A *. ( A < 45 ) )
```

Since sum sums the columns and sums the row vector that was created by the first sum. Note that this only works if the matrix is 2-dim.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is definitely to avoid loops or recursions in Matlab.

Between `sum(A(:))` and `sum(sum(A))`. 
In my experience, arrays in Matlab seems to be stored in a continuous block in memory as stacked column vectors. So the shape of A does not quite matter in `sum()`. (One can test `reshape()` and check if reshaping is fast in Matlab. If it is, then we have a reason to believe that the shape of an array is not directly related to the way the data is stored and manipulated.)

As such, there is no reason `sum(sum(A))` should be faster. It would be slower if Matlab actually creates a row vector recording the sum of each column of A first and then sum over the columns. But I think `sum(sum(A))` is very wide-spread amongst users. It is likely that they hard-code `sum(sum(A))` to be a single loop, the same to `sum(A(:))`.

Below I offer some testing results. In each test, A=rand(size) and size is specified in the displayed texts.

First is using tic toc.

```
Size 100x100
sum(A(:))
Elapsed time is 0.000025 seconds.
sum(sum(A))
Elapsed time is 0.000018 seconds.

Size 10000x1
sum(A(:))
Elapsed time is 0.000014 seconds.
sum(A)
Elapsed time is 0.000013 seconds.

Size 1000x1000
sum(A(:))
Elapsed time is 0.001641 seconds.
sum(A)
Elapsed time is 0.001561 seconds.

Size 1000000
sum(A(:))
Elapsed time is 0.002439 seconds.
sum(A)
Elapsed time is 0.001697 seconds.

Size 10000x10000
sum(A(:))
Elapsed time is 0.148504 seconds.
sum(A)
Elapsed time is 0.155160 seconds.

Size 100000000
Error using rand
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in test27 (line 70)
A=rand(100000000,1);
```

Below is using cputime

```
Size 100x100
The cputime for sum(A(:)) in seconds is 
0
The cputime for sum(sum(A)) in seconds is 
0

Size 10000x1
The cputime for sum(A(:)) in seconds is 
0
The cputime for sum(sum(A)) in seconds is 
0

Size 1000x1000
The cputime for sum(A(:)) in seconds is 
0
The cputime for sum(sum(A)) in seconds is 
0

Size 1000000
The cputime for sum(A(:)) in seconds is 
0
The cputime for sum(sum(A)) in seconds is 
0

Size 10000x10000
The cputime for sum(A(:)) in seconds is 
0.312
The cputime for sum(sum(A)) in seconds is 
0.312

Size 100000000
Error using rand
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in test27_2 (line 70)
A=rand(100000000,1);
```

In my experience, both timers are only meaningful up to .1s. So if you have similar experience with Matlab timers, none of the tests can discern `sum(A(:))` and `sum(sum(A))`.

I tried the largest size allowed on my computer a few more times.

```
Size 10000x10000
sum(A(:))
Elapsed time is 0.151256 seconds.
sum(A)
Elapsed time is 0.143937 seconds.

Size 10000x10000
sum(A(:))
Elapsed time is 0.149802 seconds.
sum(A)
Elapsed time is 0.145227 seconds.

Size 10000x10000
The cputime for sum(A(:)) in seconds is 
0.2808
The cputime for sum(sum(A)) in seconds is 
0.312

Size 10000x10000
The cputime for sum(A(:)) in seconds is 
0.312
The cputime for sum(sum(A)) in seconds is 
0.312

Size 10000x10000
The cputime for sum(A(:)) in seconds is 
0.312
The cputime for sum(sum(A)) in seconds is 
0.312
```

They seem equivalent.
Either one is good. But `sum(sum(A))` requires that you know the dimension of your array is 2.

Comment: Can someone shrink the size of the code boxes for me please? (If it's doable.)

Comment: The first is a comparison against `sum(sum(A))`, but all the rest are against just `sum(A)`...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sum up all the elements of 2-D Array

In Matlab use

Array_Sum = sum(sum(Array_Name));

Comment: Although this is not incorrect, better answers with the same information were posted months ago (Mohsen's in particular).